# How can I make a ListView header to not redraw when the items in list view do?

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

I have a list view working properly using a custom CursorAdapter. I used the method addHeaderView to have a search box on the first row of the list because it needs to go away as you scroll. However, when I actually type something in the search box, the whole listview redrwas including the header because I call notifyDataSetChanged. I don't want to redraw the header. My assumption is that I need a custom HeaderViewListAdapter but not quite sure yet.